# fatal error: cannot execute cc1 execvp" when using x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, mingw32

I'm trying to compile a file using the following command:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc reverse.cpp -o reverse.exe -s -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wno-write-strings -fno-exceptions -fmerge-all-constants -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc
```

However, I'm encountering an error: fatal error: cannot execute cc1 execvp.

I've successfully created and compiled two simple C and C++ files with a basic "hello world" program, so it seems my compiler environment is functioning properly.

I've also attempted to reinstall the build-essential package.

What might be causing this error, and how can I resolve it? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using Kali Linux

Thank you!